# How to get Column Names list if row IS NOT NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select

can i get  'colNew_name' from a select query like table below?

original table:

```
category_name | col1_name  | col2_name  | 
:------------ | :--------- | :----------|
postgres      | 1          | null       |
SAM           | null       | 1          |
MariaDB       | 1          | 1          |
```

result table:

```
category_name | col1_name  | col2_name  |      colNew_name   |
:------------ | :--------- | :----------| :------------------|
postgres      | 1          | null       |     col1_name      |
SAM           | null       | 1          |     col2_name      |
MariaDB       | 1          | 1          | col1_name,col2_name|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list of columns is small and fixed you could always do:

```
SELECT *, 
       CONCAT_WS(',', 
                 CASE WHEN col1_name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'col1_name' END,
                 CASE WHEN col2_name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'col2_name' END)
       AS "colNew_name"
FROM table1
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a88af8/2

Comment: thanks  ...but list  is around 42 columns, any other suggestions?

Comment: Give all your **real** contraints in the body of your question, if you want answers tailored to your situation. Your original table example has only 2 columns... so difficult to imagine that your real life case has 42 columns...

Comment: I wrote this large query and it works for my ,in future questions i'll add all constraints,...thanks again